# etcd error when trying to list machines

Tags: etcd

I am experimenting with etcd and have been able to get it running in a cluster and performing most of the expected functions.  However, I am trying to execute some basic admin and monitoring requests and am getting unusual errors.

I execute the following command (in the COREOS [documentation](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/0.4.7/etcd-api/#cluster-config)):

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:7001/v2/admin/machines
```

and I get the following response:

```
404 page not found
```

Note:  I confirmed that is etcd working (as I can see other commands work perfectly well).

My configuration is as follows:

```
$ etcd --version

etcd Version: 2.3.0
Git SHA: 5e6eb7e
Go Version: go1.5.3
Go OS/Arch: darwin/amd64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api you use is deprecated.

use

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:7001/members
```

or

```
curl -L http://127.0.0.1:4001/v2/members
```

Comment: With this still I am getting the same error. http://127.0.0.1:2379/v2/members, 404 page not found. I am on mac os x.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use etcd2. Also fleet allows you to interact with it easily.

Here is a sample cloud-init that works for coreos:

```
etcd2:
    discovery: "https://discovery.etcd.io/<your_token>"
    advertise-client-urls: http://$$private_ipv4:2379,http://$$private_ipv4:4001
    initial-advertise-peer-urls: http://$$private_ipv4:2380
    listen-client-urls: http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001
    listen-peer-urls: http://$$private_ipv4:2380,http://$$private_ipv4:7001
  fleet:
    etcd-servers: http://$$private_ipv4:2379
  units:
    - name: etcd2.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start
```

Then you can easily run:

```
johnt@docker ~ $ sudo fleetctl list-machines
MACHINE     IP      METADATA
cfa23XXX... 172.16.32.XXX   -
johnt@docker ~ $
```

You can also check what is in an etcd folder by running something like:

```
johnt@docker ~ $ etcdctl ls /
/coreos.com
johnt@docker ~ $
```

Comment: You might also want to check that your key from curl -s https://discovery.etcd.io/new?size=<SIZE> is registered properly.